# Modifying apk's language

Tags: apk

I am trying to modify the language of an apk. I changed all the strings. the app has 2 languages chinese and english. I was able to change the values of chinese to arabic language. But the issue is I dont know from where I can modify the selection text. Now if I choose chinese it will change to arabic. But the selection still says chinese and english.

Language selection

[image]

Now I have found some clues but I am not good at coding so I need help.

I found this code 'bg_language_text_unfocsed.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_focused="true">

    <bitmap
        android:src="@ref/0x7f070068" />
</item>

<item
    android:state_focused="false">

    <shape>

        <stroke
            android:width="dimension(1073741873)"
            android:color="@ref/0x7f05009a" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Please include the XML you actually tried. Also, please be more specific about the outcome you expect; the Arabic example is hard to follow.

Comment: I need to replace the " 中文 " text to "عربي". You see at the selection box we have 2 options 中文 and English. I already changed the content of the xml. And it is working perfectly. But Only thing now is I am not able to find this text "中文"

Comment: Hi, I found it, it was in layout xml. Thank you.